# I wonder the reason 'detached entity passed to persist' happens

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I expect that persist entity(parent) will flush automatically cause there's some changes in parent's property and I expect that children and grandson will be saved to db because of `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`

but it doesn't, and had some error detached entity passed to persist - i don't understand why those are detached entity

I tried save again right before `findAll()`, and It works

```java
 categoryRepository.save(parent);
 log.info("출력 : '{}'", categoryRepository.findAll());
```

### code

1. domain code

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MenuCategory {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
    @JsonIgnore
    private MenuCategory parent;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentId")
    private List<MenuCategory> children = new ArrayList<>();

    public MenuCategory(Long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public MenuCategory(Long id, @Size(min = 1, max = 50) String name, MenuCategory parent, List<MenuCategory> children) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.children = children;
    }

    public MenuCategory addChild(MenuCategory child) {
        children.add(child);
        child.setParent(this);
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MenuCategory{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", children=" + children +
                '}';
    }
}
```

2. testcode

```java
 @Test
    public void data_structure_test() {
        MenuCategory menuCategory = new MenuCategory(1L, "최상");
        MenuCategory parent = categoryRepository.save(menuCategory);

        MenuCategory secondCategory = new MenuCategory(2L, "1단계 첫번째");
        MenuCategory thirdCategory = new MenuCategory(3L, "1단계 두번째");

        parent.addChild(secondCategory);
        parent.addChild(thirdCategory);


        MenuCategory fourthCategory = new MenuCategory(4L, "2단계 첫번째");
        thirdCategory.addChild(fourthCategory);

        log.info("출력 : '{}'", categoryRepository.findAll());

        assertThat(categoryRepository.findById(1L).get().getChildren().size()).isEqualTo(2);
    }
```

### error

```java
2019-04-19 11:57:46.953  INFO 28426 --- [           main] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@56528192 testClass = MenuCategoryRepositoryTest, testInstance = codesquad.domain.MenuCategoryRepositoryTest@460d0a57, testMethod = data_structure_test@MenuCategoryRepositoryTest, testException = org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: codesquad.domain.MenuCategory; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: codesquad.domain.MenuCategory, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@6e0dec4a testClass = MenuCategoryRepositoryTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class codesquad.BaeminchanApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@96def03 key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManagerAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@4ae82894, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@16022d9d, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@2698dc7, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@351584c0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@e580919e, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@74294adb], contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]]

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: codesquad.domain.MenuCategory; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: codesquad.domain.MenuCategory

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:280)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy129.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at codesquad.domain.MenuCategoryRepositoryTest.data_structure_test(MenuCategoryRepositoryTest.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: codesquad.domain.MenuCategory
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persistOnFlush(SessionImpl.java:836)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$8.cascade(CascadingActions.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:392)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:500)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:432)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:395)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1398)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1483)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:307)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:629)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:593)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 40 more

2019-04-19 11:57:46.979  INFO 28426 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4722ef0c: startup date [Fri Apr 19 11:57:43 KST 2019]; root of context hierarchy
2019-04-19 11:57:46.983  INFO 28426 --- [       Thread-2] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

Comment: It's simple:the ID is supposed to be generated by the database. But you're providing the ID when creating your objects. So they're considered as detached rather than new. Also, your bidirectional OneToMany mapping is inccorrect. Read the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: Thank you : ) , I understand that hibernate consider test data as detached state for their Id. and if so, why cascade = CascadeType.MERGE work correctly?
I wonder what attribute (in hibernate CascadeType) make hibernate to consider entity with same id as detached one

Answer (score 2):

try with CascadeType.MERGE instead of CascadeType.ALL

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

Comment: thank you sir, and could i ask you why CascadeType.MERGE works but CascadeType.ALL not?